# Extended chord semitone clashes

Tags: chord-theory

I understand how, for instance, major 11 chords in their unaltered (diatonic) state are a problem as the 11th is a semitone away from the 3rd and so sharpening the 11th is a solution.
However taking the minor 9th on the ii degree as an example the 9th is a semitone away from the minor 3rd and yet this is okay. So in C, the ii degree is D, giving a m9 of DFACE - E is a semitone from F.
What gives?

Comment: I've also personally wondered why V9 of a minor key is considered OK, since the root and 9th are a minor 9th apart and still clash like heck when I play them together. Maybe it's because that particular clash is unavoidable? The only time I've used V9 of a minor key in my compositions, I purposefully wanted that painful sound.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it seems related to the way that playing a major 7th interval by itself (say F-E) sounds dissonant, but fill in the gaps to make a full major 7th chord (F-A-C-E) it becomes "pretty."

Comment: @Theodore - Honestly, I find major 7th chords to be brassy and unpleasant to listen to, to the point that I never use them in classical music (including Romantic-era-style music).

Comment: @Dekkadeci - the first few notes of 'Misty' sound brassy?

Comment: @Tim - I'm not familiar with "Misty" (I've *looked* at arrangements of it, and the piece is probably too slow for my tastes), but based on a jazz piece I did compose that starts with a major 7th chord...I guess those first few notes wouldn't sound obviously brassy. The crunch of a major 7th is generally fairly obvious to me, though.

Comment: @Dekkadeci - have a listen to Ray Stevens' version - probably not your preferred listening, but what the heck?

Comment: @Dekkadeci Maj7 chords are not much to my personal taste either (thus the scare quotes around "pretty" in my prevoius comment).  I guess they fit a particular received notion of prettiness?  I almost never use them on piano, especially voiced as in my other comment.  I do occasionally like them on guitar where the voicing is usually much wider, like A-E-A-C♯-G♯.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OP's question and other comments three chords came up `I11`, `ii9`, and `V9`, each with either a major seventh or minor ninth.

It seems to me you need to put them in their diatonic context...

[image]

In `I11` it isn't so much that the eleventh is dissonant but that it's non-tertian. Even if you don't play the third - so there is no actual minor ninth - the `F` sounds out of place. It's sort of like the third has been put in the wrong place, and that is what makes the sound jarring.

With `ii9` and `V9` the dissonant ninths form various dissonant intervals, but they are still tertian. Tertian in the sense that the eleventh is where tertian "stability" breaks down.

Also, the relative stability of tonic `I` versus more dynamic `ii` and `V` seems to matter regarding how much out of place the dissonances sound. The dissonances on `ii` and `V` add a little extra "push" when resolving to the next chords. They work with the harmonic dynamic. Whereas the eleventh on `I` works against the tertian aspect.

---

EDIT

Here is another attempt to combine chord function, scale degrees, and locating dissonant minor ninths in the various diatonic tertian stacks.

[image]

The minor ninths are highlighted red. Of those minor ninths at least one tone is either `TI` or `FA`. In the case of subdominants there are no minor ninths. In the dominants the `TI` involved in the minor ninth works with the dominant function of the chord. In the tonics the `TI` and `FA` work "contrary" to the tonic function.

Also put used hollow note heads for the stacked fifths above the roots (root, fifth, ninth, thirteenth) and solid note heads for the stacked fifths above the third (third, seventh, eleventh.) Of course if `TI` or `FA` in upper tones of either stack will result in tritones. The `TI/FA` tritone is associated with dominant function. It's interesting that the two stacks are "pure" - all perfect fifths - in the subdominant chords, contain function affirming tritones in the dominant chords, but function contradicting tritones in the tonic chords.

So one way to possibly make sense of the acceptability of the dissonances is to say the dissonant minor ninths or tritones that do occur in extended harmonies should not involve tonic function.

---

I don't necessarily find any of those ideas very convincing explanations. I'm just trying to make some sense of the original premise.

If you could somehow take the chords out of context and just play a tertian stack up to the eleventh...

[image]

...I have to honestly say I don't find it harshly dissonant. Sure, it's piquant, but it's kind of pretty too.

Sometimes in classical music a dominant seventh chord will be played over the tonic, either in a tonic pedal or as a type of suspension at a cadence. Those harmonies essential place a major seventh, major ninth, and perfect eleventh over the tonic like an incomplete `I11`. They are quite pretty, but strictly speaking those tones are NCTs which resolve not chord extensions.

To the extend that some extensions are considered unacceptable you could explain it as a contradiction of function between chord roots and the extensions.

Comment: There seems to be a contradiction here: at the outset you say the Imaj11 chord is "non-tertian", but then at the end, it's illustrated as a "tertian stack". Also, the post seems to imply that all 11th chords are non-tertian. Both points could use clarification.

Comment: @Aaron, "...I don't necessarily find any of those ideas very convincing explanations...." My personal sense is these chords all sound OK. To the extent someone else says major eleventh chords are a problem, this is how I would try to make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

They're not a semitone away, they're an octave and a bit !!

True, the note *name* sounds like it's close, but in reality, that's why it's called an 11th, or a 9th - it's just that the 11th or the 9th is over an octave from its named neighbour.

So, because there's no semitone or tone distancing the notes, there's no clash of pitches!

Sharpening or flattening the extension has little to do with the prospective clash (which isn't there anyway). Consider '7♯9' (Hendrix chord) which has an M3 in the basic triad, and ♯9 (sounding exactly like m3). Put next to each other, it sounds horrible. Separate them by an octave, it works!

Comment: I think you've missed the point of the question. By your logic, Maj11 chords would not be avoided in the way OP is referring to, but they are, because the dissonance of the 11 against the 3 is quite harsh.

Comment: As Aaron has stated, the point has been missed.  I should have mentioned I get totally the octave apart thing. But this doesn't explain why a major 11 is considered wrong. Since the 3rd and 11th are also over an octave apart

Answer (score 0):

The convention is an aesthetic one, but there is an important technical difference between the two chords in question.

In a Maj11 chord, the 3 and 11 are are a minor ninth apart. For example, in a root position CMaj11 chord, `C E G B D F`, the E and F are a minor ninth apart.

In a Min9 chord, the 3 and 9 are a major seventh apart. For example, in a root position D-11 chord, `D F A C E`, the E and F (or, rather, the F and E) are a minor seventh apart.

In addition, the 11 in a Maj11 chord is dissonant not just against the 3, but also against the 1, 5, and 7. There are fewer dissonances in the Min9 chord. In that chord, the 9 is dissonant against the 1 and 3 only.

I will posit an answer, but again, since it's a fundamentally aesthetic question, this will be debatable: the problem is that the 11 (or the 4) has much stronger tendency to resolve to the 3 than the 9 does to either the 3 or 1. It's the sheer strength of that pull of the 11 that overwhelms the chord in a way the the 9 doesn't.

Comment: I think your first portion hits the nail on the head the way I've always conceptualized it: when this half step is voiced as a major seventh, it softens the dissonance. But the half step voiced as a minor second (or minor ninth), especially from the chordal third, is more problematic.

Comment: Maybe it is the tritone to the 7th that spells doom for the Maj11? I will try it as an add 11, see if that helps...